# Почему нельзя объявить массив указателей?

Tags: c++

Почему так можно:

```
int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
int A[] = {a, b, c},
    B[] = {c, b, a};
```

а так нельзя:

```
int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
int* A[] = {&a, &b, &c},
     B[] = {&c, &b, &a};
```

И ещё: почему нельзя объявить массив *ссылок*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

У вас ошибка возникает когда вы объявляете массив `B` типа `int` , а не указатель на тип `int`. Первая звездочка относится к первому объявлению массива `A`, а ко второму массиву она не имеет никакого отношения, поэтому ее надо указать второй раз перед объявлением массива `B` вот так:

```
int main(){
    int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
    int * A[] = {&a, &b, &c}, * B[] = {&a, &b, &c};

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

> И почему нельзя объявить массив ссылок?

С разрешением "массивов ссылок" в рамках языка С++ появилась бы масса концептуальных проблем. В языке С++ ссылочные типы не являются *объектными* типами и формально не занимают памяти (т.е. языком не специфицируется, занимают ли ссылки память). По этой причине, в частности, в языке не существует *указателей* на ссылки и невозможно узнать "размер" ссылки через `sizeof`.

А отсутствие указателей на ссылки тут же само по себе "блокирует" возможность создания массивов ссылок, ибо в С++ (как и в С) вся основная функциональность встроенных массивов фундаментально завязана на возможность array-to-pointer conversion, т.е. на возможность формирования указателей на элементы массива и выполнения над ними адресной арифметики.

Answer (score 4):

Перепишите чуть иначе:

```
int *A[] = {&a, &b, &c},
    B[]  = {&c, &b, &a};
```

И стало ясно, почему. Знак `*` относится только к первому объявлению.

Comment: Та же самая ситуация возникает при объявлении вроде `int* a, b` - тут указателем объявляется только `a`, а вот `b` является обычным `int`, читать надо как `int *a, b`